# how to write if else in universe builder

Tags: business-objects, universe

I am new to development in business objects universe development, now I am struck in writing the if else in universe.

My requirement is

I have created a filter with string names `Yesterday` and `Last Sunday`.

In my report if filter is selected as `yesterday` then automatically select query should have the date filtering as `yesterday` and same should be the case when I select `Last sunday`.

Can any one give me the idea on how to acheive.

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact workflow?  How are you implementing the filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the full details, i would say in this situation you would have 2 objects in the universe for this, one being the date object that you want to filter against (e.g. invoice date), the other being generic date objects set to yesterday and last sunday.

**Please note the following code is based upon an Oracle database, if your database is different please refer to your approriate documentation and/or db admin for your syntax**

For a "Yesterday" object create a date-type dimension object with the following select statement, ensuring the object format follows your reporting conventions:

```
trunc(sysdate-1)
```

For a "Last Sunday" object again create a date-type dimension object with the following select statement:

```
trunc(next_day(sysdate-7,'SUNDAY'))
```

In your report to filter by the required date, you'd pull the date field you want into the query filters pane, select "Object from this query" in the parameter window and select the newly created "Yesterday" or "Last Sunday" object for the parameter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks chizo this is the one I am looking for.